# Do pattern implicit rules get executed even if there was another rule already that match the target?

Tags: makefile

Basically, if I have a target that already has a rule but still match another pattern implicit rule. How make handles this situation?

```
targ.bin :: dep

dep: some-req
   some rules

%.bin : some-reqs
   some rules
```

In this case do both rules apply on targ.bin? Meaning, would dep be called with it's prereqs and rules then make executed the %.bin pattern implicit prereqs and rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the GNU Make manual [4.13 Double-Colon Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html),
especially:

> Each double-colon rule should specify a recipe; if it does not, an implicit rule will be used if one applies. See Using Implicit Rules.

Your double-colon rule:

```
targ.bin :: dep
```

has no recipe. Therefore it only expresses the dependency `targ.bin` -> `dep`
and the implicit rule:

```
%.bin : some-reqs
   some rules
```

specifies that `targ.bin` shall be made up-to-date by executing:

```
some rules
```

as well as implying the dependency `targ.bin` -> `some-reqs`.

Make combines all prerequisites of target `targ.bin`. So your Makefile implies that:

```
dep: some-req
   some rules

targ.bin : some-reqs dep
   some rules
```

is the complete recipe for `targ.bin`. As bourne out by:

**Makefile**

```
targ.bin :: dep

dep: a
    echo '$@ -> $^'

%.bin : b
    echo '$@ -> $^'
```

which runs like:

```
$ touch a b
$ make
echo 'dep -> a'
dep -> a
echo 'targ.bin -> b dep'
targ.bin -> b dep
```

**Later**

> Assuming in the example you provided the double-colon rule had a recipe, does that mean the implicit one wont be applied?

See [10.1 Using Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Implicit.html#Using-Implicit), especially:

> In general, make searches for an implicit rule for each target, and for each double-colon rule, that has no recipe.

So yes, if the double-colon rule had a recipe the implicit rule would not be applied. I'll leave the experiment to you.

Comment: Thanks. Assuming in the example you provided the double-colon rule had a recipe, does that mean the implicit one wont be applied? (%.bin : b)

Comment: @SFbay007 See extended answer